# @dargmuesli/nuxt-cookie-control with nuxt 2

Tags: cookies, nuxt.js

I am trying to use @dargmuesli/nuxt-cookie-control for my nuxt 2 project but the autoimporting seems not to be working. Is there a way to use the  component without autoimporting. Is there a specific way to use this library with nuxt 2?

Tryed to use Coockie Control with the following configuration
cookieControl: {
barPosition: 'bottom-full',
cookies: {
necessary: [
{
name: {
en: 'Authentication',
fi: 'Todennus',
},

```
            description: {
                en: 'Used for customer authentication',
                fi: 'Käytetään asiakkaan todentamiseen',
            },
            cookies: [
                'auth._token.local',
                'auth._token_expiration.local',
            ],
        },
    ],
    optional: [],
    
    closeModalOnClickOutside: false,

    isCookieIdVisible: true,
    locales: ['en', 'fi'],
},
```

}

And when i used the  component in /layouts/default i got the following exception in the browser

known custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.